# UTF-32 encoding in Erlang

Tags: erlang, utf-32, wxerlang

I want to create an application with wxErlang, in which I need to use UTF-32 strings. I can load source code from the file with UTF-8 encoding, but getting errors when the file is converted to UTF-32. I need to use Cyrillic characters in my application, that's why I want to solve this problem with UTF-32 encoding.

Comment: You can write any and all code points in UTF-8, and doing so is preferable to USC-32 for numerous reasons. I'm not sure why you're using USC-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [unicode usage in Erlang page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html), you'll see that the current release of Erlang, 16A, supports UTF-8 source files. UTF-32 is not supported.  However, if you want Cyrillic, UTF-8 has everything you can write in UTF-32.